# Count lines of a dataset in function of a column in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, count

I'm working with PySpark. I have a dataset like this:

[image]

I want to count lines of my dataset in function of my "Column3" column.
For example, here I want to get this dataset:

[image]

Comment: `ur_df.groupBy('column3').agg(count('*').alias('count')).sort('column3').show(10, False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pyspark.sql.functions.count(col)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.count):
Aggregate function: returns the number of items in a group.

```
temp = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 11, 'A'),
    (1, 12, 'B'),
    (2, 13, 'B'),
    (0, 14, 'A'),
    (1, 15, 'c'),
    (2, 16, 'A'),
], ["column1", "column2", 'column3'])

temp.groupBy('column3').agg(count('*').alias('count')).sort('column3').show(10, False)
# +-------+-----+
# |column3|count|
# +-------+-----+
# |A      |3    |
# |B      |2    |
# |c      |1    |
# +-------+-----+
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupBy('column_3').count()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.